# Why is this code not working as intended? Python

Tags: python, function

```
import string

decimal1 = 55
binary1 = 0

def convert(decimal1, binary1):
    binary1 = str(decimal1 % 2) + str(binary1)
    decimal1 = decimal1//2
    if decimal1 == 0:
        binary1 = str(binary1)
        return binary1
    convert(decimal1, binary1)
x = convert(decimal1, binary1)
print(x[-1])
```

I wanted a code that converts decimal to binary but the function output is not being taken into x or the program is the returning none. I want to understand why it is happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to reteurn the result, then you don't need to pass `binary1` variable.

```
import string

decimal1 = 55

def convert(decimal1):
    value = str(decimal1 % 2)
    decimal1 = decimal1//2
    if decimal1 == 0:
        return value
    else:
        return convert(decimal1) + value


x = convert(decimal1)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function only has one `return` statement, for the base case. You need a `return` for the recursive case, too.

When the recursion finishes, in your case the value is just thrown away because there's no `return`. Python isn't like other languages that return the value of the last expression. If there's no return statement, it returns `None` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To debug recursion problems like this it can be helpful to visualize whats happening. If you post OPs code in this recursion visualizer [here](https://www.recursionvisualizer.com/?function_definition=import%20string%0A%0Adef%20convert%28decimal1%2C%20binary1%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20binary1%20%3D%20str%28decimal1%20%25%202%29%20%2B%20str%28binary1%29%0A%20%20%20%20decimal1%20%3D%20decimal1%2F%2F2%0A%20%20%20%20if%20decimal1%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20binary1%20%3D%20str%28binary1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20binary1%0A%20%20%20%20convert%28decimal1%2C%20binary1%29%0A&function_call=convert%2855%2C%200%29) you can see the return value isnt bubbling up, as it does in the selected answer [here](https://www.recursionvisualizer.com/?function_definition=import%20string%0A%0A%0Adef%20convert%28decimal1%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20value%20%3D%20str%28decimal1%20%25%202%29%0A%20%20%20%20decimal1%20%3D%20decimal1%2F%2F2%0A%20%20%20%20if%20decimal1%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20value%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20convert%28decimal1%29%20%2B%20value%0A%0A&function_call=convert%2855%29).